# Symfony docker container don't manage to connect to mariadb container

Tags: mysql, docker, symfony, mariadb

I'm using docker to run :

- Symfony image
- MariaDB image

Here is my **docker-compose.yaml** file :

```
version: '2'
services:
  myapp:
    image: 'bitnami/symfony:1'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    environment:
      - SYMFONY_PROJECT_NAME=backend
      - MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MARIADB_USER=monty
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=monty
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=test
    container_name: symfony_container
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=test
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MARIADB_ROOT_USER=root
    container_name: mariadb
```

I start both containers with the command :

```
docker-compose up
```

That generates a "backend" directory, representing the Symfony install.

In that directory, I manage to create an entity with:

```
php bin/console make:entity
```

but then, when I run the command:

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

I get the following errors :

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution 

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution    

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I guess the error might come from some of the user parameters.

Yet when I run the command

```
docker-compose exec mariadb mysql -u monty -p
```

and enter the password "monty", I manage to access my database, so I don't quite understand why my symfony container could not.

If I enter the symfony container with command :

```
docker exec -it symfony_container bash
```

This command works:

```
php bin/console make:entity
```

But the command

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

return the following errors:

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'bitnami_myapp' 

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'bitnami_myapp'

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'bitnami_myapp'
```

I edited the docker-compose.yml file located at "/app" inside the Symfony container, and it has the exact same pieces of information as the docker-compose.yml file above.

Thanks for the reply!

UPDATE :

Abdennour Toumi answer solve a part of my issue, thanks!

The other part regarding the 'bitnami_myapp' unknown database came from the .env.local file, that still had default database in parameter.

Comment: Are you running that php command from within the docker container?

Comment: no, from the "backend" file created by docker-compose file

Comment: What is "backend" file? We need some more information about how you run the commands. Please give all the steps.

Comment: I've edited it, let me know if you need more specifications.

Comment: ssh into the container with `docker exec -it symfony_container bash` and run the command there, if you are not doing that already

Comment: I edited my post to add errors coming from inside the container.

Comment: Where did you define `bitnami_myapp` as the database name? I wonder if a .env file would take priority over it or not; but wherever is defined, you just need to change that to match your `test` database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the following env vars In **mariadb** service,

```
  - MARIADB_USER=monty
  - MARIADB_PASSWORD=monty
```

then, run `docker-compose up -d` again.

Indeed, I tried to reproduce your environment, and it works after adding these env vars:

[image]

The full docker-compose is now :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  myapp:
    image: 'bitnami/symfony:1'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    environment:
      - SYMFONY_PROJECT_NAME=backend
      - MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MARIADB_USER=monty
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=monty
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=test
    container_name: symfony_container
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=test
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MARIADB_ROOT_USER=root
      - MARIADB_USER=monty
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=monty
    container_name: mariadb
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've added the missing fields, my docker-compose look word for words like yours now, but I still got following errors :  "Unknown database 'bitnami_myapp", even though I execute the commands inside the symfony container

Comment: I don't get where the "bitnami_myapp" database comes from though

Comment: Which version of docker-compose are you using?

Comment: latest ::: 1.25.4